# Jquery countdown: How to make callbacks at different moment of the countdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple requirement.

- When a page displays, a countdown starting from 30 minutes is displayed at the bottom-right of the page.
- The countdown is hidden after 15 seconds.
- 1 minutes before the expiration, the countdown is displayed again till the end.
- At the expiration, a javascript alert is displayed to tell the user the time is up.

  ```
  $("#divCountdown")
     .countdown(timeToExpire, function (event) {
        $(this).text(
          event.strftime('%M:%S')
        );
        //15 seconds later do something
        //1740 seconds later, i.e. 29 minutes, do something
        //1800 seconds later, i.e. 30 minutes, do something
  })
  ```

The above code allows me to display the countdown. Is there a way to make callbacks while the countdown is going on? The first one after 15 seconds so that I can hide the div that displays the countdown, 1 minute before the expiration, display it again, and at the end, display the JavaScript popup?

Thansk for helping

Comment: What is `countdown`? Your plugin? Where is its code?

Comment: It came from this plugin: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: Why not ask its author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you already know how to hide, show or change the inner text of an HTML tag and that it is already in the correct place of your HTML. Let us focus on how the countdown should work:

```
$(function() {
    //Initialization
    var minutes = 30;
    var seconds = 0;
    //Make sure your div exists
    var countDownContext = $("#divCountdown");
    //Showing things initially
    countDownContext.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    //15 seconds
    var initialTime = 15;
    //We store the interval to be able to stop the repetition later
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        //Are we still inside those 15 seconds at the start?
        if (initialTime > 0) {
            //Was this the last second?
            if (--initialTime === 0) {
                //Then hide
                countDownContext.hide();
            }
        }
        //We decrease seconds and check whether it, before decreasing was 0
        if (seconds-- === 0) {
            //If it was, then we decrease a minute and set seconds to 59
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        }
        //Refresh inner text
        countDownContext.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        //Is the last minute reached?
        if ((minutes === 1) && (seconds === 0)) {
            //Then show
            countDownContext.show();
        }
        //Is the time expired?
        if ((minutes <= 0) && (seconds <= 0)) {
            //Then alert about it
            alert("Your time is up");
            //And clear the interval
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

EDIT:

The same logic as described here can be used with the plugin you intend to use, take a look at [this](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/website-launch.html) example.

Comment: I would like to kindly ask for the reason of the downvote. Was this question down-voted because it did not use count-down plugin?

Comment: After it counted down to 29:59 it stopped counting, look at your solution, and try to improve it, I believe this is the coolest answer, if only it works.

using switch

Comment: @PreciousTom thanks so much for your constructive criticism. There was a misspelling in the solution, unfortunately in the original text I have written `setTimeout`, whereas `setInterval` was the correct call, already edited the answer. Now I'm testing the counter.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#event-object the event object provides access to the totalMinutes/totalSeconds remaining on the countdown you can combine this with the `update.countdown` and `finish.countdown` events for something like

```
$("#divCountdown")
   .countdown(timeToExpire, function (event) {
      $(this).text(
        event.strftime('%M:%S')
      );
}).on('update.countdown',function(event) {
   //check event.offset.totalMinutes value to show/hide object
}).on('finish.countdown',function(event){
   //display alert
});
```

Comment: I've put an alert inside the update.finish portion of the function, but the alert is not being displayed.

Comment: @Richard77 sorry it should of been `finish.countdown` not `update.finish` i've amended the answer

Answer (score 2):

You've already got a handler being called every second, so just do some math to determine elapsed/remaining time:

```
var $countdown = $("#divCountdown"),
    countdownMinutes = 30,
    timeStart = new Date().getTime(),
    timeEnd = timeStart + countdownMinutes * 60 * 1000;

$countdown
    .countdown(timeEnd, function (e) {

        var now = e.timeStamp,
            secondsElapsed = Math.floor((now - timeStart) / 1000),
            secondsRemaining = Math.ceil((timeEnd - now) / 1000);

        $countdown.text(e.strftime('%M:%S'));

        switch (secondsElapsed) {
            case 15:
                $countdown.hide();
                break;
        }

        switch (secondsRemaining) {
            case 60:
                $countdown.show();
                break;
        }
    })
    .on('finish.countdown', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('boom');
        });
    });
```

Comment: When I put this code inside <script></script> tags, I'm getting an error with the lambda expression.

Comment: No ECMA6? Okay, added semicolons and function keyword. If you still see an error, please post it.

Comment: It's working fine. The only thing that I noticed is that the alert is happening at `00:01`, which is fine with me. However, users may as well forget the feature and focus only on that minor flow. I've tried to put this line `$countdown.text("00:00");` above the alert `alert('boom');`, but each time, the alert is executing before the text is set to `00:00`. Any idea why, the alert is being executed before, although it comes after?

Comment: It's probably because the trigger for the callback isn't aligned with the seconds - that's why I added the `Math.ceil`. I suspect using `update.finish` event for that is best, as Simon pointed out.

Comment: Adding an alert in the update.finish didn't solve the problem. At `00:01`, the alert popup was displayed.

Comment: I was able to replicate in Safari, but the previous code worked fine for me in Mac Chrome/Firefox. Frankly, that's an issue for the plugin developer, but nonetheless I've added the `finish` handler, and adding a timeout allows the redraw to occur before the alert.